# python doesn't go out from while loop when try except conditions

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I have the following code:

```
from fractions import Fraction
p= input("Input the chance of occurrence")
while True:
    try:
        p=float(p)
        break
    except ValueError:
        try:
            p=float(sum(Fraction(s) for s in p.split()))
            break
            
        except:
            print("I don't understand the given input")
            continue
```

The thing is that when the third case is given, it doesn't ask for another input, instead continues printing "I don't understand the given input", so, how can I prevent this
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to ask for a new input inside the loop. Your current code is just looping endlessly on the first value.

Comment: It is a while loop. Once you provide the input, it is continuing

Comment: Now I see, I've modified my code putting the input  inside the loop and worked, thanks both of you